# Tie an enable pin to ground when another pin is high

Tags: serial, ttl

I am designing a simple circuit with two ICs. IC1 has an enable pin that is internally pulled up with a 10Kohm resistor. To disable IC1 you have to tie this pin to ground.

IC2 has an serial presence detection pin that is high when presence is detected. When presence is not detected <s>it seems to be "undefined," i.e. it's not guaranteed to be low</s> it will be low.

What I'd like to do is disable IC1 when serial presence is not detected. So I have to tie IC1 EN to GND when IC2 SPD is <s>not high</s> low.

For some reason this is breaking my brain, and I can't seem to find an answer via googling, which leads me to be believe that I'm not googling the right terms. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

The ICs are actually little breakout modules. IC1 is an [Adafruit Ultimate GPS Breakout](https://www.adafruit.com/product/5440), based on the [PA1616D IC](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/5186/5186_PA1616D_Datasheet.pdf).

IC2 is a [Pololu 23201a Serial Adapter](https://www.pololu.com/product/126), based on the [MAX3238 IC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max3238.pdf).

EDIT 2:

For further context I am attempting to implement the circuit described [here](https://www.finnie.org/2019/01/18/so-you-want-a-stratum-1-ntp-server/) with some refinements such as disabling the  GPS IC when the serial cable is disconnected.

Comment: Will a resistor do? Or what are the specs of the inputs and outputs to be connected together? Even better, say what those mystery chips are and give a link to data sheet so we can read what we need from the data sheets.

Comment: @Justme Added above. Thank you in advance!

Comment: 'When presence is not detected it seems to be "undefined," i.e. it's not guaranteed to be low.' – Is it guaranteed to be high-impedance when presence is not detected? Presumably the pin does _something_ different depending on whether presence is detected or not; it's unlikely that they designed it so that, for example, it's high when presence is detected and also high when presence is not detected.

Comment: The problem is that you are not specific about which pins you mean, and the breakout board has no manual or schematics to tell how it works. The RS232 level shift IC is mentioned and it has an output called "invalid", but that is a push-pull output. So nothing indicates the adapter has detect output which either pushes high or leaves floating. Please explain in detail how you have connected things together, in such detail that someone could e.g. buy same products and replicate your setup and measure what you are doing. It might be that your description is faulty.

Comment: @TannerSwett That makes sense. I was only looking at the description of the Pololu serial adapter. I challenged myself to look at the datasheet for the MAX3238 IC and yes it looks like it will be low if presence is not detected. However I am unable to discern whether or not it will be high-impedence.

Comment: @mwp if you think it does not pull low, then it won't pull low if you put a pull-up resistor of say 10k.

Comment: @Justme I'm certain my description is faulty. Yes, I'm referring to the /INV output. The Pololu product overview simply says this: "A connection detection line gives your project additional options for responding to a physical connection to a serial port."

Comment: The IC datasheet says: "INVALID is high (valid data) if any receiver input voltage is greater than 2.7 V or less than −2.7 V, or has been between −0.3 V and 0.3 V for less than 30 µs. INVALID is low (invalid data) if all receiver input voltages are between −0.3 V and 0.3 V for more than 30 µs. Refer to Figure 5 for receiver input levels."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the INV pin is directly coming from RS232 chip, it is a push pull output.

Low when proper voltages not detected, high when proper voltages are detected.

So if the GPS is enabled by high and disabled by low, the pins can be simply be wired together.

Comment: Well, that would certainly be a simple solution. So because it's push-pull it will simply absorb any current from the /EN pin that's pulled high to +5V? i.e. it can act as a sink? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes, push pull CMOS outputs do sink current when low and source current when high. The INV output was rated for about 1mA so it can drive a 10k pull-up.

Comment: Neat. And may I ask how you were able to ascertain that it's a push-pull output?

Comment: @mwp The chip datasheet said it is.

Comment: OK. I can't find the word "pull" or "push" anywhere in that document but it's already been established that I'm clueless. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @mwp It does not explicitly say it being a push-pull type output, but it does say when it is high and low without explicitly mentioning it isn't a special output like open-drain type, and the pin specs indicate current and voltage specs when high and low, so it must be a push pull output. It is also never said to be tristated to high impedance, like the other outputs are when shut off.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this depending on your preferred level of complexity/cost. Please update your question with any requirements you have.

One pretty simple solution would be to add a pull-down resistor on the the IC2 serial detection output line and then input it to a comparator IC. Tie the comparator output to the IC1 EN pin. When Serial detection is high, the comparator outputs high, IC1 is enabled. When serial detection is undefined, the resistor pulls it low, the comparator outputs low, IC2 is disabled.

Comment: I am going to assume the problem description in the question is wrong, the output is push-pull so there is nothing needed to make the output and input compatible.